# Can't start foreman in Heroku Tutorial using Python

Tags: python, ruby, heroku, foreman, git-bash

I have been attempting to complete [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python), but have run into a problem with the `foreman start` line.  I am using a windows 7, 64 bit machine and am attempting to do this in the git bash terminal provided by the Heroku Toolbelt.

When I enter `foreman start` I receive:

```
sh.exe": /c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/bin/foreman: "c:/Program: bad
interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So I tried entering the cmd in git bash by typing `cmd` and then using `foreman start` (similar to [a comment on one of the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157917/foreman-start-with-a-manual-path) suggests).  This is what that produced:

```
Bad file descriptor
c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.62.0
/lib/foreman/engine.rb:377:in `read_nonblock'
c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.62.0
/lib/foreman/engine.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in watch_for_output'
c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.62.0
/lib/foreman/engine.rb:373:in `loop'
c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.62.0
/lib/foreman/engine.rb:373:in `block in watch_for_output'
21:06:08 web.1  | exited with code 1
21:06:08 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
```

I have no clue what the second set of errors is trying to tell me, since the file location it seems to claim engine.rb is running from does not even exist on my computer.

I have looked at other answers to similar problems, however I am not receiving similar errors and so do not believe a solution to my problem currently exists.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I had this problem. I fixed it by uninstalling version 0.62 of the foreman gem and installing 0.61.

```
gem uninstall foreman
gem install foreman -v 0.61
```

Comment: however, would you you happen to know how I can actually view the page now? I tried going to 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0:5000 in my chrome web browser, and I got an error 108.  I tried `curl 0.0.0.0` and `curl 0.0.0.0:5000` in a separate git bash terminal, and those gave me `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`. any ideas?

Comment: ok, I managed to visit it after deploying to heroku, but I am still wondering how I can visist it when testing with foreman?

Comment: If you follow the Heroku guide the website should be running on 127.0.0.1:5000 or localhost:5000

Comment: After I install foreman 0.61, I get this error on "foreman start"

  `02:54:38 web.1  | started with pid 6504
  02:54:38 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
  02:54:38 web.1  |   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\gunicorn-script.py",   line 9, in <module>
  ...02:54:38 web.1  |   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-  packages\distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2311, in load_entry_point
  02:54:38 web.1  | exited with code 1
  02:54:38 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
  02:54:38        |     return ep.load()`

Comment: I had a similar error on Mac... Foreman would not start because the 'command not found' error. I thought it could be a $PATH issues since I just updated to Ruby 1.9.3, but I just installed it with 'foreman start' and I'm all set! Then I ran 'bundle install' to get the remaining gems for my app.

Comment: Not a good user experience Heroku. This is 2014 and this problem is not fixed. If we can't install it using directory with spaces, just told us so. Now, installing foreman 0.61 still not worked for me, ` ImportError: No module named fcntl' Not cool. So not cool...

I think I will use OSX for this. I believe the experience will be different...I hope..

Answer (score 11):

Yes, heroku-toolbelt-installer is not working correctly at present (30-Aug-2013).
For windows the following steps worked for me:

1. uninstall heroku (via windows 'program uninstall')
2. install heroku https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows into C:\bin\heroku , i.e. 'no spaces'
3. install ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
4. in cmd run "gem install foreman -v 0.61". Yes, "gem install foreman" installed v0.63, which does not work for "foreman start"
5. in cmd "foreman start" works for the heroku hello-world example

Comment: what version of Ruby should I use?

Answer (score 6):

Uninstalling the heroku toolbelt and reinstall it to a path that does not have spaces in it, for example `C:\heorku\` will help a bit. Aside from that the heroku windows installer is horribly broken at the moment, not exactly a point of pride for us. To work around the issue with foreman you can set the environment variables your self using `export VAR=VALUE` and then run your app using what ever commands you put in your procfile.

This is going to improve in the future.

Comment: How should I uninstall it? I can't seem to find any suggested instructions, but when I tried to use the control panel to "remove program" (of "Herkou 2.35.0") it said it couldn't uninstall it and said that it might be because it was already uninstalled?

Comment: The path suggestion didn't help with the "Bad file descriptor" issue.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add is that if you install Heroku to a directory with spaces, that will also cause an error when you try and do `gem install foreman -v 0.61` (on Windows).

Once I'd reinstalled Heroku to C:\Heroku instead of C:\Program Files\Heroku then I was able to make this work using Eric Speelman's solution above.