# How do I troubleshoot a "Bad file descriptor" message in Foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

Using a Windows 7 64-bit machine with the latest railsinstaller.org installer and no previous installations, I am having a problem when I follow these steps in the Git Extensions BASH terminal.

I have created a new app, using:

```
rails new testapp
```

then I do:

```
gem install foreman
```

and it gives me:

```
Bad file descriptor
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0/lib/foreman/
engine.rb:372:in `read_nonblock'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0/lib/foreman/
engine.rb:372:in `block (2 levels) in watch_for_output'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0/lib/foreman/
engine.rb:368:in `loop'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0/lib/foreman/
engine.rb:368:in `block in watch_for_output'
20:57:01 web.1  | exited with code 0
20:57:01 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
```

How should I start troubleshooting this?

Comment: Hello, CamronBute. Haven't you solved this problem?

Comment: @kio21 nope! not yet...

Comment: Just tried 'gem uninstall foreman'
'gem install foreman -v 0.61' as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399637/cant-start-foreman-in-heroku-tutorial-using-python) and it helped me.

Comment: Perhaps it might be something of a library compatibility issue, on the syscall end? @casper suggested an incompatibility for git-bash under some MinGW/MSYS Ruby builds, in remark under [Switch to inspect mode. - WIndows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638056/switch-to-inspect-mode-windows-10)