# Switch to inspect mode. - WIndows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i got a prompt "Switch to inspect mode." when i do

```
rails c
```

it shows

```
    Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.4)
    Switch to inspect mode.
```

and I can't do anything only type "exit" to exit this console but I'd like to check last post in my website by typing

```
@post = Post.last
```

when i type **irb** it shows me the same.

ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]
git-bash
I don't know what to do, I've tried to find a solution but futilely. Am I supposed to install linux to learn how to program in ruby on rails? XDD

edit: when i Type: `@post = Post.last` it shows

```html
Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Errno::EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb/input-method.rb:42:in `winsize'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb/input-method.rb:42:in `winsize'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:753:in `output_value'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:545:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:704:in `signal_status'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:538:in `block in eval_input'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb:166:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb:151:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb:151:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb:150:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb:150:in `each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:537:in `eval_input'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:472:in `block in run'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:471:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:471:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.7/lib/irb.rb:400:in `start'
Maybe IRB bug!
```

Comment: Your Ruby is not necessarily compatible with git-bash. You should run it under MinGW or MSYS shell, if that was what it was built with. Or try basic Windows command prompt too.