# Foreman installed by heroku toolbelt on windows can't be found

Tags: windows, heroku, foreman, heroku-toolbelt

I simply followed the getting started with nodejs tutorial from Heroku.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#declare-process-types-with-procfile

But I get an error at the part "declare process types with procfile"
My problem is that my cmd (using windows 7) didn't find the command "foreman"

Any solutions ?
I downloaded/installed the heroku toolbelt, the login works fine, but foreman dont

Comment: It sounds like the heroku toolbelt isn't working correctly for windows. There are some suggestions you might want to try in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399637/cant-start-foreman-in-heroku-tutorial-using-python) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434287/foreman-start-fails-on-windows-following-heroku-tutorial), or you can [open a new issue](https://github.com/heroku/toolbelt/issues?labels=windows&page=1&state=open) with the heroku toolbelt. I don't see any open issues that are exactly your problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows7 64-bit, using git's bash.  Here's what I did:

- uninstall the toolbelt, Ruby, and Git using Control Panel's "Program and Features"
- reinstall the toolbelt to `C:\Heroku` (see [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159765/215945) for more info)
- add `C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin;C:\Heroku\ruby-1.9.2\bin` to the system PATH variable: Control Panel, System, Advanced system settings, Environment Variables..., System variables, Variable `Path`, Edit...  (Change `ruby-1.9.2` if a future version of the toolbelt includes a newer version of Ruby.)
- open a git bash window and uninstall foreman version 0.63
  `$ gem uninstall foreman`
- then install version 0.61 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15726134/215945) for more info)
  `$ gem install foreman -v 0.61`

Now foreman worked for me:
`$ foreman start`

Comment: Simply uninstalling and reinstalling foreman 0.61, and adding the heroku\ruby-1.9.2\bin to PATH was enough for it to work for me.

Comment: Simply adding ruby to path was enough for me. I am still using foreman 0.63

Comment: SAme here, only had to add ruby to system path.

Comment: @ddollar should really get this fixed.

Comment: @MichaelKariv Hi, I have posted new question about Javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836760/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-in-chrome.Please help me out

Answer (score 7):

You can do this without uninstall/reinstall:

1. Open Environment Variables
2. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\ruby-x.x.x\bin` to system path (assuming that you installed heroku toolbelt in this directory).
3. You're done! try it by opening a new shell window and typing `foreman start` .

Comment: Good point. Some systems may require a reboot. Mine did not, although I did need to close my shell and open it again.

Answer (score 3):

Foreman finished support for Windows. You can use `forego` instead. It is a foreman implementation in GO lang.

https://github.com/ddollar/forego

Comment: Yes, forego worked for me as well. But even better, Heroku recently added a new command 'heroku local', which uses forego behind the scenes. Just install the latest version of Heroku Toolbelt to enable it. And as you say, Heroku no longer support the use of foreman.

Answer (score 1):

Adding **C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\ruby-1.9.3\bin** to the Environment variable PATH worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Heroku toolbelt, I was getting weird errors about required modules when running `foreman start`.  Adding the ruby bin directory to path, and reopening the shell window did not work for me.  It seems that foreman was never installed!  When I attempted to uninstall foreman, ruby told me it was not installed.  So I ran `gem install foreman`, and 0.77 was installed.  One gotcha, I had to open the shell to install the foreman gem as Administrator.  Maybe that is how the Heroku toolbelt seems to not have installed properly the first time.  Running `foreman start` seemed to do something after it was installed (naturally).