# Run Ruby-generated `foreman` in GitBash, Windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, command-line-interface, git-bash, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to run **foreman** inside my GitBash (Windows 7).

I installed it as part of the Heroku-Toolbelt for Windows, and added **C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\ruby-1.9.3\bin** to the path. It works in **cmd**, but that disrupts my workflow.

The error I get...

```
$ foreman
sh.exe": /c/PROGRA~2/Heroku/RUBY-1~1.3/bin/foreman: "C:/Program: bad interpreter
: No such file or directory
```

The issue I find is in the HashBang line inside foreman...

```
#!"C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe"
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'foreman' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'foreman', version
load Gem.bin_path('foreman', 'foreman', version)
```

The HashBang line doesn't correctly resolve to the Ruby executable, because of the space in **C:/Program Files (x86)/...**

I've tried escaping the space with '\', I've tried adding extra "s. I'm at a loss.
**How do I get that HashBang line to resolve?**

PS: First question asked, not sure if I "asked" to StackFlow standards, thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the answers on StackOverflow - and yes I did look before posting :P

Answer source here:
[Foreman installed by heroku toolbelt on windows can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078939/foreman-installed-by-heroku-toolbelt-on-windows-cant-be-found)

My summary:

1. To get *foreman* working in GitBash, you have to install *heroku-toolbelt* in a folder that contains **no spaces** - I used *C:\Heroku*

But then an answer to a problem I dan't even encountered yet!
For forman to actually work, you have to revert to an older version, v0.61 to be precise**. So...

```
gem uninstall foreman && gem install foreman -v 0.61
```

That did the trick, it now works for me! Yay!

> **The foreman version that came installed on my heroku-toolbelt was v0.74